# One genral inquisitiveness about highcharts:

Tags: highcharts

If we have to create a chart with lots data eg- "performance of stock for last 5 yrs- do we have to transfer all data to the client side for highcharts to process it? Wont involve too much data overheads?

Regards
Utsav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "lazy load" chart data, see the [example in the documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading).